NG0602 when using RxDB reactivity factory
My use case: Use a reactive rxDB.collection.find().$$() inside a computed angular signal. I am quite sure I am misreading the current documentation :/
Reading the current RxDB documentation I can see that I can make RxDB provide Angular Signals via the reactivityFactory (awesome!!!). If I follow the documentation I end up with an NG0602 error since we cannot create signals within a reactive context. See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxdb-15-angular-17-playground-azqzjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
The issue comes from the fact, that
protected cars = computed(() => {
    if (this.isLoading()) return [];
    return this.db.cars.find().$$();
  });

internally calls the reactivityFactory.
If I work around this issue e.g. by using the toLazySignal util from ngxtension it creates a signal everytime a collection change happens, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxdb-15-angular-17-playground-1ky4q9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (open the browser console)
How should I implement the reactivityFactory corretly so that my use case works?

the stackblitz you provided does not throw error you mentioned in orginal question, Can you please update?

The first one does: https://ibb.co/DKWv6Sy The second one only logs whenever a new signal is created

Solved! The issue was a total different one. The observable actually returned an error, which was swallowed by toSignal.
The error:
Error (QU13): RxError (QU13):
A top level field of the query is not included in the schema
Given parameters: {
schema:{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "encrypted": [],
  "indexes": [
...

That was the reason why the signal got create again immediately which created an endless loop that ended in a browser crash. Adding rejectErrors: true to the toSignal options helped a lot.
So the reactivity factory should be something like this:
export function createReactivityFactory(injector: Injector): RxReactivityFactory<Signal<any>> {
  return {
    fromObservable(observable$, initialValue: any) {
      return untracked(() =>
        toSignal(observable$, {
          initialValue,
          injector,
          rejectErrors: true
        })
      );
    }
  };
}

Edit: The updated documentation: https://rxdb.info/reactivity.html#adding-a-custom-reactivity-factory-in-angular-projects
